# Inconsistent numbers of samples error from Python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, kaggle

I'm working on the Titanic competition on Spyder IDE.  The code is barely complete but I'm doing it one step at a time (and this is the first time I've ever built a learning model).  Now, I'm getting a `Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [891, 183]` error in the log while trying to run my code.  This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

train_path = "C:\\Users\\Omar\\Downloads\\Titanic Data\\train.csv"
train_data = pd.read_csv(train_path)
columns_of_interest = ['Survived','Pclass', 'Sex', 'Age']
filtered_titanic_data = train_data.dropna(axis=0)

x = train_data[columns_of_interest]
y = filtered_titanic_data.Survived

train_x, val_x, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)

titanic_model = DecisionTreeRegressor()
titanic_model.fit(train_x, train_y)

val_predictions = titanic_model.predict(val_x)

print(filtered_titanic_data)
```

Idk whether its coming from the excel file or the parameters.  I'm sorry if this is a simple question.  I couldn't implement other people's solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are taking labels from filtered data and taking `x` from unfiltered data

Change the following line

```
x = train_data[columns_of_interest]
```

to

```
x = filtered_titanic_data[columns_of_interest]
```